# Make a call function with RPC endpoints or other method

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I start developing my own NEAR client because I thought that could be a nice personal project. The problem is with call function, because the near doc only mention view function in the page about rpc endpoints. I dont know if there is some special connection for call function or the page abouts call functions with rpc endpoints in not write. But I need know  how call a call function.

Comment: Have you tried this https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-call? It has an example on how to call a method, not only view it.

Comment: @John I know about it, the problem is that I am creating my own client, and the near-cli uses near-api-js which is really messy to read the source code. Btw, I am using c++ to develop the cli, not javascript

Answer (score 4):

Basically, a "change" method is a transaction made from one account (the caller / signer) to the contract account (receiver). Transactions on the NEAR network are constituted by a collection of `Actions`. In the case of making a function call, the relevant action is the `FunctionCall` action.

Here's a link to the `Transaction` documentation: https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/transaction#transaction.

[near-cli-rs](https://github.com/near/near-cli-rs), [`near-call`](https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-call) and [near-api-js](https://github.com/near/near-api-js) are tools that simplify this process, but we can step through it in detail to better understand it.

Before we jump in, take a look at [this example](https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs/blob/56b1a7d0b45b34ee29d7afc018906ebd374a1d09/examples/contract_change_method.rs) in the [near-jsonrpc-client](https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs) repo which is a code implementation of the method described here.

First, you need to make sure the access key you have available is either permissioned for `FullAccess` or is a `FunctionCall` access key permitted to make that function call. See https://near-sdk.io/zero-to-hero/beginner/logging-in#access-keys.

We can start off by viewing the access keys via the [`query`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/access-keys#view-access-key) RPC method.

```bash
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=query \
  params:='{
    "request_type": "view_access_key",
    "finality": "final",
    "account_id": "signer.testnet",
    "public_key": "ed25519:AeKTfwxjMxbroVoW3HuueKdqJN5vHxrXjmoUvK2oCT2D"
  }'
```

The response of which would be something like this;

```json
{
  "result": {
    "nonce": 80,
    "permission": {
      "FunctionCall": { ... }
    },
    ...
    "block_hash": "87HZEuCyDp8WQd7ixEHLUmM1LwKKAQAqLUiPASWojeqx"
  },
}
```

Seeing as we now have our `nonce` and `block_hash`, we are good to go.

So, everything we need for our transaction is available. The last little piece is the `FunctionCall` action itself, which is an object containing the following fields;

- `method_name`: the change method of the contract you're calling.
- `args`: JSON-formatted argument list.
- `gas`: https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas
- `deposit`: (for payable methods) https://www.near-sdk.io/contract-interface/payable-methods

Now, we can see everything start to come together, our transaction now looks something like this;

```json
{
  "signer_id": "signer.near",
  "public_key": "ed25519:AeKTfwxjMxbroVoW3HuueKdqJN5vHxrXjmoUvK2oCT2D",
  "nonce": "<CURRENT_NONCE + 1>",
  "receiver_id": "receiver.testnet",
  "block_hash": "<LATEST_BLOCK_HASH>",
  "actions": [
    {
      "functionCall": {
        "method_name": "greet",
        "args": { "name": "John Wick" },
        "gas": 100000000000000,
        "deposit": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What's left is to serialize all of that using the [borsh](https://github.com/near/borsh) binary format with [this schema](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/e92725352a5ad33db7ba97f4d181da44af88267f/src/transaction.ts#L149-L160).

Once we've serialized our transaction, we then need to sign it with our private key, convert the bytes to base64 and finally broadcast it using either the [`broadcast_tx_async`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/transactions#send-transaction-async) or [`broadcast_tx_commit`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/transactions#send-transaction-await) RPC methods.

```bash
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=broadcast_tx_async \
    params:='[
        "DwAAAG5lYXJrYXQudGVzdG5ldABuTi5L1rwnlb35hc9tn5WELkxfiGfGh1Q5aeGNQDejo0QAAAAAAAAAEAAAAGpvc2hmb3JkLnRlc3RuZXSiWAc6W9KlqXS5fK+vjFRDV5pAxHRKU0srKX/cmdRTBgEAAAADAAAAoe3MzhvC0wAAAAAAAAB9rOE9zc5zQYLL1j6VTh3I4fQbERs6I07gJfrAC6jo8DB4HolR9Xps3v4qrZxkgZjwv6wB0QOROM4UEbeOaBoB"
    ]'
```

Depending on what tools you're using, I recommend you either use the Rust version of the client – [near-jsonrpc-client](https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs) or [near-api-js](https://github.com/near/near-api-js).

Also consider using the interactive [near-cli-rs](https://github.com/near/near-cli-rs).